# Xcode - directory not found for option FacebookSDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I opened an older app that I got off my Google Drive and get the following errors when I tried to compile.  I have tried deleting the FacebookSDK, then re-adding it.  Also, deleting search paths, then deleting FacebookSDK and re-adding.  Still experiencing the same error.  Does anyone have some advice on how I can solve this?

Here is a snapshot of my error message:
[image]

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: not sure what's the -pie flag for, do you remember adding that ?

Comment: This is a project from a former employer that I now am working on, so I haven't looked into that yet.

Comment: try to search for that in project : build settings.

Comment: nothing came up when I searched in build settings

Comment: did you search in both the project and the target ? also select "All" (Show all Build Settings) and "Combined" (Show the effective value of build settings...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the framework, check "Destination: Copy items if needed".

EDIT:
In light of the comments, you should update your FacebookSDK and refactor the code that doesn't work anymore, because you risk doing this process again, of integrating it in a month or so when the SDK becomes obsolete again.

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started) are the steps that you need to follow to integrate it again with your project.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I made sure to check the "Destination: Copy items if needed" checkbox when adding the file, still the same error.

Comment: not sure here, but you might also want to move the whole project to an upper directory as you might encounter a path that is too long

Comment: did you also add the framework in Targets : Build Phases, link binary with Libraries ?

Comment: Well thats the thing, when I go to search frameworks in the Link Binary with Libraries section, the FacebookSDK.framework isn't even available there anymore, does that mean I'll need to scrap all of the Facebook integration in the app and start over with an updated Framework version like Social.framework or Facebook's API?

Comment: hope it's not redundant but you are following the steps from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started), right ?

Comment: I tried adding the updated Framework, but it caused errors in just about every piece of code that had to do with Facebook.  So I figured I could make it work with this older framework version.

Comment: you should add the latest version of the framework as the old ones get obsolete and don't work as expected, i know they changed it many times this year, and the integration didn't work properly with their apis.

Comment: So basically you are saying I'll need to add the new Facebook API, delete all of the old stuff that was with the FacebookSDK.framework, and update all of the code within my app to the newest API syntax?

Comment: Yep, if you don't do this at this stage, even if you manage to fix the old framework, you might find that it doesn't work anymore because it's obsolete. Sure, you can check if it's compatible in their release notes by looking at your local framework version and searching it on the web / facebook developer webpage.